# Negation - I am not <that> as you requested

Tags: sentence-construction, negation

> I am not ... as you requested

Was i required to be <...> or not (e.g. an Umpalumpa)? is this ambiguous, alter the meaning?

I omit the request here to avoid contextual clues. I failed to reword the sentence on the spot, but I guess that would have been best to avoid ambiguity. On the other hand, the meaning is clear from context, so the question is purely about grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's ambiguous.  But context clues would have a major impact, so it's not really an issue.  If it is still ambiguous, you can separate the ending phrase from the word just before it in a number of ways to solve the problem.

Insert a comma: "**I am not late, as you requested.**"  (slightly ambiguous)

Re-order the phrases: "**As you requested, I am not late.**"

Add words: "**I am not as late as you requested.**" (opposite request, but meaning also slightly changed -- now considering the degree of lateness)

Comment: But the third one doesn't work with objects, does it: "I am not as an Umpalumpa as you requested"?

Comment: So you think the comma makes the difference? I thought so, too. Thanks.

Comment: However, does omission of the comma make any sense at all without further modification?

Comment: It feels weird without the comma, yes.  By the way, you could say, "I am not as much of an Umpalumpa as you requested." ... or ... "I am not the Umpalumpa that you requested."   Also possible is "I am not as Umpalumpa as you requested." which turns it into an adjective, but that's probably not what you wanted.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit that into your answer. "the" was the option I had in mind before. thx again. In fact, I answered a request for private tuition, so that's why I was sensitive to the language. But my question here really was, albeit not clear, how to negate "as requested".